# rgdal not working in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, geospatial, gdal, rgdal

I have recently switched from windows to ubuntu and can't make the rgdal package working properly.

I know there are a lot of posts on this but I just can't make it work.

I have installed `gdal` following https://gist.github.com/lossyrob/4348503
but still rgdal is in my list of installed packages according to `rgdal%in%installed.packages()` but when I include with `library(rgdal)` it returns `Error in library(rgdal) : there is no package called ‘rgdal’`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I had seen that already, I ran $ sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev libproj-dev installed and updated the apt-file I do not get any errors but I am not allowed to include the library. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just installed on my ubuntu desktop, its working , use install.packages("rgdal"),choose a cran mirror nearby you, see if that works.

Comment: i tried to reinstall rgdal as suggested by @EDi and now it gives an error `configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/irene/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rgdal’`

Comment: sorry guys i feel superstupid but following the link @pradeep6kumar suggested i found the package needed with $ apt-file search proj_api.h
libproj-dev: /usr/include/proj_api.h but how do I install it? because sudo apt-get install /usr/include/proj_api.h returns Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package /usr/include

Comment: I take the packages from the ubuntugis-unstable ppa. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable ; sudo apt-get update;  sudo apt-get install libproj-dev`

Comment: When I run the update it returns 'Fetched 2,183 B in 1s (1,277 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gm-notify-maintainers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gm-notify-maintainers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was the gmail notifier after all that I had installed according to [this post](http://marcosbox.blogspot.it/2010/05/gmail-notify-il-notificatore-gmail.html) (in Italian sorry)...

This is how I did it, thanks to everybody, I wouldn't have made it without you guys!

So according to what was returned by `sudo apt-get update` and according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa) I unticked the similarly named PPA with the URL shown in the error message.

I re-ran what @EDi suggested `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable ; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libproj-dev` and it worked like a charm!

I spent so much time on this.... Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is also a binary package in the `c2d4u` repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgdal
```

That way you don't have to compile it at all.